# Can't create more than one table with Websql/Chrome

Tags: sqlite, google-chrome

I can't create more than one table on a Chrome App dadabase
Here is a snippet of the code:

```
lk.webdb.open = function() {
  var dbSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10MB
  lk.webdb.db = openDatabase("SSW3", "1.0", "SEO SERP Workbench", dbSize);
}

lk.webdb.createTable = function() {
var db = lk.webdb.db;
db.transaction(function(tx) {
  tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, setid INTEGER , day DATETIME , engine TEXT, query TEXT , url TEXT , position INTEGER )", []);
  tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sets (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, name TEXT )", []);
  });
}
```

The table `items` is created, if not existing, the table `sets` never gets created.

Moreover, before trying this, I wanted to create multiple `items` tables, named items1,items2,etc depending on the active user project, but again, when the database has no tables, the first is created, but not any other.

Looking in the web and the W3C docs I haven't found ONE example of creating more than one table, but looks like only one table can be created for each DB (that's absurd) or I'm simply doing things in the wrong way ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the following code and had no problems in creating both tables:

```
var db = openDatabase("SSW3", "1.0", "SEO SERP Workbench", 10 * 1024 * 1024);
db.transaction(function (tx) {
  tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, setid INTEGER , day DATETIME , engine TEXT, query TEXT , url TEXT , position INTEGER )", []);
  tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sets (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, name TEXT )", [] );
});
```